# Calling a DLL from Visual Studio VB 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dll

I have just started with VB.NET (Visual Studio 2015) and having trouble with a very basic required to call a DLL written in assembler.   Calling the DLL in assemble is reasonably straight forward but in VB it is eluding me.  Here is my code

```
Declare Function getDLLInfo Lib "c:\temp\exporter.dll" ()
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles    Button1.Click

    Call getDLLInfo.ExportMe()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

The ExportMe method does not return a value but simply opens a dialogue box to indicated success.  The exception that I received from Visual Studio is

```
{"PInvoke restriction: cannot return variants."}
```

The DLL code is shown here

```
ExportMe:
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

push 0
push VA(Title)
push VA(Text)
push 0
call [VA(MessageBoxA)]

mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret
```

It is obvious that the method does not return anything but what is the restriction calling the method? Can anyone help sort this mystery out?

Comment: You declared the `getDLLInfo` without a return type. This may not necessarily do what you think it does. Use `Option Strict On` and `Option Explicit On`, and declare the return type of your function.

Comment: Thanks GSerg, I had tried that but got the same error.  No matter what type I declared.

Comment: You should declare the actual type it returns, not "any type." Does it return a pointer to an object that has a method called `ExportMe`? What kind of object is that?

Comment: Here is the actual code 
ExportMe:
 push ebp
 mov ebp, esp
 
 push 0
 push VA(Title)
 push VA(Text)
 push 0
 call [VA(MessageBoxA)]
 
 mov esp, ebp
 pop ebp
 ret

Comment: I meant the `getDLLInfo` function, not `ExportMe`. What does it return?

Comment: The getDLLInfo is just the DLL library that I have listed in the edit to the question above.

Comment: There is no such thing as "just the DLL library." If you declare it as a function, it must exist as a function (in that library). If there is no function in the first place, you don't declare it. If all you have is `ExportMe`, you should have written `Declare Sub ExportMe Lib "c:\temp\exporter.dll" ()`.

Comment: Many thanks.  Yes that solved it.   I was labouring under a misapprehension.  I assumed that I was declaring the library name and not the function or method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not declare the library itself in VB, you only declare individual functions from the library. The library name only appears in the `Lib` clause.

If `ExportMe` is your only function, you should simply write

```
Declare Ansi Sub ExportMe Lib "c:\temp\exporter.dll" ()
```